# Find The Full tr value and bind it in json format to send to api

Tags: jquery

A set of data has been printed to my html page in tabular format which comes for another api in json format,I have attached the picture below[image]

[image]

As you can see there are several checkboxes, what i want to do here is when the checkboxes are checked and i hit initiate RPA button ,the checkboxes I selected using those checkboxes jquery will find site and cabinet data from its closest tr and then it will bind the data in below given json format

```
{ "siteList": [ 
    { "siteName": "Site1", 
        "deviceList": [ 
            { "deviceName": "S1device1"}, 
            { "deviceName": "S1device2"} 
            ] 
    },
{ "siteName": "Site2", 
        "deviceList": [ 
            { "deviceName": "S2device1"}, 
            { "deviceName": "S2device2"} 
            ] 
    }, 
    { "siteName": "Site3", 
        "deviceList": [ 
            { "deviceName": "S3device1"  }, 
            { "deviceName": "S3device2"} 
            ] 
    },  
] 
}
```

Here is the code i tried

```
   $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('#faliure').css('display', 'none');
  $('#success').css('display', 'none');
  

  var checks = [];

function get_checks(e) {
  $(e).each(function(x, o) {
    var siteListMain = {}
    if ($(e).is(":checked")) {
      let getTds = $(e).closest('tr').find('td')
      let siteName = getTds.eq(1).text()
      let cabinet = getTds.eq(2).text()
      siteListMain.siteList = siteName
      siteListMain.deviceName = cabinet
      checks.push(siteListMain)
    } else {
      checks.splice(checks.indexOf(siteListMain), 1)
    }
  })
}

 $('#certLogonForm').validate({

          rules: {
          // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
          // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
          // on the right side
          j_username: "required",
          j_password: "required"
          
        },
        // Specify validation error messages
        messages: {
          j_username: "Please enter username",
          j_password: "Please enter password"
        },


        submitHandler: function(form,e) {
          e.preventDefault();
         console.log(checks)
            console.log(checks);
            var tr_data = [];
          var check_length = checks.length;
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://reqres.in/api/login",
                type: "GET",
                data: $(form).serialize(),

                beforeSend: function() {
                  $("#imageload").show();
                  $('#logonuidfield').attr('readonly', true);
                  $('#logonpassfield').attr('readonly', true);
                  // xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("pd_adeptcom_bnd:xk8MU9TR"));
                
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    // $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle');
                    $("#imageload").hide();
                    $('#success').css('display','block');
                    $('#faliure').css('display','none');
                   
                    $('#info').html('Total 0 cabinets selected estimated hours 0 hours');
                   
                 $("#sub").attr("disabled", true);


                },            
                error:function(error)
               {
                  $("#imageload").hide();
                  $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle');
                  $('#faliure').css('display','block');
                   $('#success').css('display','none');
               }
        });
    }
});
 

    });
```

whenever I console log checks [] []

please help me fix this problem, any help wil be highly appreciated
Thank you in advance

Comment: you want to store all data of checked `tr` with checbox and push that checkbox and tr data to an array ?

Comment: So you are able to build that JSON data you have above ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Yes

Comment: Just confirming you store data in checks Array on checkbox `onclick` function `get_checks` or when you click on the initiate RPA button ?

Comment: that one is not for this purpose that one is for another

Comment: Cool. So for this you want want the data to be stored on button click initiate RPA of the checked input closest `tr`  ?

Comment: yup sir , you got it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `$.each` on the actual `checked` checkbox. Also, in your JSON API `table` data you need to use an `onchange` function rather then `onclick`- In this we send the data of the `tr -> td ->` to our `checksArray`.

Once you are done selecting the `checkboxes` you can click on `initiate RPA` button you will see the `console.log` of all the `checkboxes` which are checked and their closest `tr` data.

Also, if you `uncheck` the checkbox the that item will removed from the `checkArray` for that we can use `splice()` method.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5f54c4ac4d8ce4111389dc46/1',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    //$("#imagelodaing").show();
    xhr.setRequestHeader("secret-key", "$2b$10$NQY9ge9Lc7fr9E98t6wcGuBiQ1ckBgbxN0fpbL2qIF9/zzOH30NXm");
  },
  success: function(json) {
    var j = 1;
    json.siteList.forEach(function(data) {
      data.deviceList.forEach(function(values) {
        var time = (values.count * 25) / 60;
        $('#data_table').append("<tr>" + "<td><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='check' id='checked_box" + j + "' value='" + j + " 'onchange='get_checks(this)' ></td>" + "<td>" + data.siteName + "</td>" + "<td>" + values.deviceName + "</td>" + "<td>" + values.count + "</td>" + "<td>" + parseFloat(time).toFixed(2) + " Min" + "</td>" + "<input type='hidden' class='time' id='count' name='count[]' value=" + time + ">" + "</tr>");
        if (values.status == "READY") {
          $('#checked_box' + j + '').attr('disabled', true);
          $('#checked_box' + j + '').closest("tr").addClass('table-active');
        } else if (values.status == "IN PROGRESS") {
          $('#checked_box' + j + '').attr('disabled', true);
          $('#checked_box' + j + '').closest("tr").addClass('table-active');
        }
        j++
      })
    })
  },
  error: function() {
    //$("#imagelodaing").hide();
  }
});

var checks = [];

function get_checks(e) {
  $(e).each(function(x, o) {
    var siteListMain = {}
    if ($(e).is(":checked")) {
      let getTds = $(e).closest('tr').find('td')
      let siteName = getTds.eq(1).text()
      let cabinet = getTds.eq(2).text()
      siteListMain.siteList = siteName
      siteListMain.deviceName = cabinet
      checks.push(siteListMain)
    } else {
      checks.splice(checks.indexOf(siteListMain), 1)
    }
  })
}

function initiateRPA() {
  console.log(checks); //check array data for all selected checkboxes
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data_table"></table>
<button onclick="initiateRPA()">
  Initiata RPA
</button>
```

Comment: ..cant I do this inside jquery because I have to bond and send this data to api

Comment: @Swarnadeep you can call initiate rpa from anywhere Inside your jquery. Becasue as soon as you select the checkbox the data is is pushed into your checks array.

Comment: pyaxis_index_admin.html:78 Uncaught ReferenceError: initiateRPA is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick  this error is coming

Comment: Can you add your complete code like HTML jquery. So that I help further -  I have already provided your the answer based on this question you asked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63784476/bind-in-json-format-from-two-different-arrays-in-jquery

Comment: can u please have a look on the above link